# Highcharts - Position the legend navigation to right

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have a chart with legends. but when legend items count goes big, then legend navigation automatically appears at the bottom of legends.
Any way using which I can position the legend navigation buttons to the right also change its orientation?

Refer image below for better understanding of requirement:
[highchart-legend-navigation-position-change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5biLA.png)

legend configuration:

```
{
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            enabled: true,
            maxHeight: 60,
            
            itemStyle: {
                font: '10px Source Sans Pro, sans-serif'
            },
            navigation: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                },
                animation: true,
                arrowSize: 8
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there was a topic like this on the official forum some time ago: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44524

It is not possible to set this using the API, to achieve something like this it is necessary to overwrite functions such as `H.Legend.prototype.positionCheckboxes`, `H.Legend.prototype.scroll` `H.Legend.prototype.handleOverflow` responsible for generating navigation. Unfortunately, this is not a perfect solution and would require further refinement.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/var2x3cy/